# Is it possible to use property in the src path

Tags: c#, razor

I would like to use `@store.Name` in the `src="../Pandora.jpg"`.

At the moment my code is:

```
<img src="../Pandora.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="@store.Name Logo">
```

but I want something like:

```
<img src="../@store.Name.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="@store.Name Logo">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible with Razor syntax. Make sure that you need to use `@()` to append the string and avoid `.jpg` treat as the nested property.

```
<img src="../@(store.Name).jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="@store.Name Logo">
```

[Demo @ .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tIj3z1)